# Corrupted files with Camel Ftp component

Tags: apache-camel, ftp-client, camel-ftp

I'm using apache camel to make a ftp client for downloading some files to some local directory. The program reads a xml file to get the name of the file that will be fetched from the ftp.The program seems to work except that the files downloaded are corrupted. Right now I'm trying to download some image files but the ones I get are 14.9Kb and corrupted, no error message shown.

This is my code:

main

```
    public void main() throws FileNotFoundException {
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
        RutaFtp routeBuilder = new RutaFtp();
        CamelContext ctx = new DefaultCamelContext();

        try {
            ctx.addRoutes(routeBuilder);
            ctx.start();
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            ctx.stop();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

camel route:

```
from("file:./?fileName=Datos.xml&noop=true")
        .split(xpath("//Datos/imagen/text()"))
        .setProperty("rutaArchivo", this.body())
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "imagen: ${body}")
        .process(ExtraerNombre).to("direct:ftp").end(); 

        from("direct:ftp")  
        .pollEnrich("ftp://"+user+"@"+ftp+"/?password="+password+"&recursive=true&passiveMode=true&fileName=${body}&delete="+borrado+"")
        .to("file:C:/outputFolder?flatten=true").end();
    }
```

I've tried using the streamDownload parameter but tha prevents the files to be downloaded (I don't know why)

```
.pollEnrich("ftp://"+user+"@"+ftp+"/?password="+password+"&recursive=true&passiveMode=true&streamDownload=true&fileName=${body}&delete="+borrado+"")
```

console log:

> INFO | Apache Camel 2.15.1.redhat-621084 (CamelContext: camel-1) is
>   starting 0 [main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext  -
>   Apache Camel 2.15.1.redhat-621084 (CamelContext: camel-1) is starting 
>   INFO | JMX is enabled 10 [main] INFO
>   org.apache.camel.management.ManagedManagementStrategy  - JMX is
>   enabled  INFO | Loaded 185 type converters 208 [main] INFO
>   org.apache.camel.impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  - Loaded 185
>   type converters  INFO | AllowUseOriginalMessage is enabled. If access
>   to the original message is not needed, then its recommended to turn
>   this option off as it may improve performance. 395 [main] INFO
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext  - AllowUseOriginalMessage
>   is enabled. If access to the original message is not needed, then its
>   recommended to turn this option off as it may improve performance. 
>   INFO | StreamCaching is not in use. If using streams then its
>   recommended to enable stream caching. See more details at
>   http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html 395 [main] INFO
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext  - StreamCaching is not in
>   use. If using streams then its recommended to enable stream caching.
>   See more details at http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html  INFO
>   | Endpoint is configured with noop=true so forcing endpoint to be
>   idempotent as well 395 [main] INFO
>   org.apache.camel.component.file.FileEndpoint  - Endpoint is configured
>   with noop=true so forcing endpoint to be idempotent as well  INFO |
>   Using default memory based idempotent repository with cache max size:
>   1000 395 [main] INFO org.apache.camel.component.file.FileEndpoint  -
>   Using default memory based idempotent repository with cache max size:
>   1000  INFO | Route: route1 started and consuming from:
>   Endpoint[file://./?fileName=Datos.xml&noop=true] 502 [main] INFO
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext  - Route: route1 started and
>   consuming from: Endpoint[file://./?fileName=Datos.xml&noop=true]  INFO
>   | Route: route2 started and consuming from: Endpoint[direct://ftp] 504
>   [main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext  - Route: route2
>   started and consuming from: Endpoint[direct://ftp]  INFO | Total 2
>   routes, of which 2 is started. 504 [main] INFO
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext  - Total 2 routes, of which
>   2 is started.  INFO | Apache Camel 2.15.1.redhat-621084 (CamelContext:
>   camel-1) started in 0.504 seconds 507 [main] INFO
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext  - Apache Camel
>   2.15.1.redhat-621084 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 0.504 seconds  INFO | Created default XPathFactory
>   com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathFactoryImpl@5434283f 1533
>   [Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - file://./] INFO
>   org.apache.camel.builder.xml.XPathBuilder  - Created default
>   XPathFactory
>   com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathFactoryImpl@5434283f  INFO
>   | imagen: ftp://190.0.56.190:8021/pruebasumman/conductor/71708375.jpg
>   1635 [Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - file://./] INFO route1  - imagen:
>   ftp://190.0.56.190:8021/pruebasumman/conductor/71708375.jpg  INFO |
>   Apache Camel 2.15.1.redhat-621084 (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutting
>   down 10521 [main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext  -
>   Apache Camel 2.15.1.redhat-621084 (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutting
>   down  INFO | Starting to graceful shutdown 2 routes (timeout 300
>   seconds) 10524 [main] INFO
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy  - Starting to graceful
>   shutdown 2 routes (timeout 300 seconds)  INFO | Waiting as there are
>   still 3 inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 300
>   seconds. 10524 [Camel (camel-1) thread #2 - ShutdownTask] INFO
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy  - Waiting as there are
>   still 3 inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 300
>   seconds.  INFO | Waiting as there are still 3 inflight and pending
>   exchanges to complete, timeout in 299 seconds. 11525 [Camel (camel-1)
>   thread #2 - ShutdownTask] INFO
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy  - Waiting as there are
>   still 3 inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 299
>   seconds.  INFO | Waiting as there are still 3 inflight and pending
>   exchanges to complete, timeout in 298 seconds. 12528 [Camel (camel-1)
>   thread #2 - ShutdownTask] INFO
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy  - Waiting as there are
>   still 3 inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 298
>   seconds.  INFO | Waiting as there are still 3 inflight and pending
>   exchanges to complete, timeout in 297 seconds. 13529 [Camel (camel-1)
>   thread #2 - ShutdownTask] INFO
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy  - Waiting as there are
>   still 3 inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 297
>   seconds.  INFO | Waiting as there are still 3 inflight and pending
>   exchanges to complete, timeout in 296 seconds. 14540 [Camel (camel-1)
>   thread #2 - ShutdownTask] INFO
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy  - Waiting as there are
>   still 3 inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 296
>   seconds.  INFO | Waiting as there are still 3 inflight and pending
>   exchanges to complete, timeout in 295 seconds. 15555 [Camel (camel-1)
>   thread #2 - ShutdownTask] INFO
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy  - Waiting as there are
>   still 3 inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 295
>   seconds.  INFO | Waiting as there are still 3 inflight and pending
>   exchanges to complete, timeout in 294 seconds. 16568 [Camel (camel-1)
>   thread #2 - ShutdownTask] INFO
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy  - Waiting as there are
>   still 3 inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 294
>   seconds.  INFO | Waiting as there are still 3 inflight and pending
>   exchanges to complete, timeout in 293 seconds. 17569 [Camel (camel-1)
>   thread #2 - ShutdownTask] INFO
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy  - Waiting as there are
>   still 3 inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 293
>   seconds.  INFO | Waiting as there are still 3 inflight and pending
>   exchanges to complete, timeout in 292 seconds. 18574 [Camel (camel-1)
>   thread #2 - ShutdownTask] INFO
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy  - Waiting as there are
>   still 3 inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 292
>   seconds.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Download image file in **binary mode**

By default, Camel FTP is downloading file by ASCII mode.

Add `binary=true` into your ftp route will turn from ASCII mode to binary mode